# Scrapy: Error 10054 after retrying image download

Tags: python, scrapy, urllib

I'm running a Scrapy spider in python to scrape images from a website. One of the images fails to download (even if I try to download it regularly through the site) which is an internal error for the site. This is fine, I don't care about trying to get the image, I just want to skip over the image when it fails and move onto the other images, but I keep getting a 10054 error.

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 588,
> in _runCallbacks
>     current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)   File "C:\Python27\Scripts\nhtsa\nhtsa\spiders\NHTSA_spider.py", line 137,
> in parse_photo_page
>     self.retrievePhoto(base_url_photo + url[0], url_text)   File "C:\Python27\Scripts\nhtsa\nhtsa\retrying.py", line 49, in wrapped_f
>     return Retrying(*dargs, **dkw).call(f, *args, **kw)   File "C:\Python27\Scripts\nhtsa\nhtsa\retrying.py", line 212, in call
>     raise attempt.get()   File "C:\Python27\Scripts\nhtsa\nhtsa\retrying.py", line 247, in get
>     six.reraise(self.value[0], self.value[1], self.value[2])   File "C:\Python27\Scripts\nhtsa\nhtsa\retrying.py", line 200, in call
>     attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs), attempt_number, False)   File "C:\Python27\Scripts\nhtsa\nhtsa\spiders\NHTSA_spider.py", line
> 216, in retrievePhoto
>     code.write(f.read())   File "c:\python27\lib\socket.py", line 355, in read
>     data = self._sock.recv(rbufsize)   File "c:\python27\lib\httplib.py", line 612, in read
>     s = self.fp.read(amt)   File "c:\python27\lib\socket.py", line 384, in read
>     data = self._sock.recv(left) error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
```

Here is my parse function that looks at the photo page and finds the important url's:

```
def parse_photo_page(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//table[@id="tblData"]/tr'):
            url = sel.xpath('td/font/a/@href').extract()
            table_fields = sel.xpath('td/font/text()').extract()
            if url:
                base_url_photo = "http://www-nrd.nhtsa.dot.gov/"
                url_text = table_fields[3]
                url_text = string.replace(url_text, "&nbsp","")
                url_text = string.replace(url_text," ","")  
                self.retrievePhoto(base_url_photo + url[0], url_text)
```

Here is my download function with retry decorator:

```
from retrying import retry
@retry(stop_max_attempt_number=5, wait_fixed=2000)
    def retrievePhoto(self, url, filename): 
        fullPath = self.saveLocation + "/" + filename
        urllib.urlretrieve(url, fullPath)
```

It retries the download 5 times, but then throws the 10054 error and does not continue to the next image. How can I get the spider to continue after retrying? Again, I don't care about downloading the problem image, I just want to skip over it.

Comment: It's not recommended to mix synchronous network IO (such as `urllib.urlretrieve`) and async IO (scrapy/twisted). In any case, after 5 retries, `self.retrievePhoto(base_url_photo + url[0], url_text)` can still raise an exception. You need to catch that within a `try: ... except:...` if you want to continue with loop iterations in `parse_photo_page`. Scrapy has an [`ImagesPipeline`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#using-the-images-pipeline) to retrieve images aynchronously.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'm attempting to implement an ImagesPipeline now...can't quite get it to work, I'm not impressed with the documentation for this

Comment: @JohnK: are you saying that you would like to contribute to the open source project by improving the documentation?

Comment: @StevenAlmeroth is there somewhere to comment on that?

Comment: @JohnK: sure, the best way is to issue a [pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/proposing-changes-to-a-project-with-pull-requests/) for your proposed changes to  the [media pipeline documentation](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/docs/topics/media-pipeline.rst).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct that you shouldn't use `urllib` inside scrapy because it blocks everything. Try to read resources related to "scrapy twisted" and "scrapy asynchronous". Anyway... I don't believe that your main problem is with "continue after retrying" but with not using "relevant xpaths" on your expressions. Here is a version that works for me (Note the `./` in `'./td/font/a/@href'`):

```
import scrapy
import string
import urllib
import os

class MyspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "myspider"
    start_urls = (
        'file:index.html',
    )

    saveLocation = os.getcwd()

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//table[@id="tblData"]/tr'):
            url = sel.xpath('./td/font/a/@href').extract()
            table_fields = sel.xpath('./td/font/text()').extract()
            if url:
                base_url_photo = "http://www-nrd.nhtsa.dot.gov/"
                url_text = table_fields[3]
                url_text = string.replace(url_text, "&nbsp","")
                url_text = string.replace(url_text," ","")
                self.retrievePhoto(base_url_photo + url[0], url_text)

    from retrying import retry
    @retry(stop_max_attempt_number=5, wait_fixed=2000)
    def retrievePhoto(self, url, filename): 
        fullPath = self.saveLocation + "/" + filename
        urllib.urlretrieve(url, fullPath)
```

And here's a (much better) version that follows your patterns but uses `ImagesPipeline` that @paul trmbrth mentioned.

```
import scrapy
import string
import os

class MyspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "myspider2"
    start_urls = (
        'file:index.html',
    )

    saveLocation = os.getcwd()

    custom_settings = {
        "ITEM_PIPELINES": {'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1},
        "IMAGES_STORE": saveLocation
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        image_urls = []
        image_texts = []
        for sel in response.xpath('//table[@id="tblData"]/tr'):
            url = sel.xpath('./td/font/a/@href').extract()
            table_fields = sel.xpath('./td/font/text()').extract()
            if url:
                base_url_photo = "http://www-nrd.nhtsa.dot.gov/"
                url_text = table_fields[3]
                url_text = string.replace(url_text, "&nbsp","")
                url_text = string.replace(url_text," ","")
                image_urls.append(base_url_photo + url[0])
                image_texts.append(url_text)

        return {"image_urls": image_urls, "image_texts": image_texts}
```

The demo file I use is this:

```
$ cat index.html 
<table id="tblData"><tr>

<td><font>hi <a href="img/2015/cav.jpg"> foo </a> <span /> <span /> green.jpg     </font></td>

</tr><tr>

<td><font>hi <a href="img/2015/caw.jpg"> foo </a> <span /> <span /> blue.jpg     </font></td>

</tr></table>
```

Comment: Thanks alot @neverlastn !! I agree that the image pipeline is the way to go. I was attempting to implement a pipeline yesterday and couldn't quite get it to work. That little snippet for the custom_settings did it for me, I think my settings.py file wasn't being properly referenced. Again, thanks for your complete answer.

Comment: You're welcome! :) I think that `settings.py` is the proper way to do this. `custom_settings` is a little hack - not very clean! I just put it there to have a simple self-contained answer.

Comment: "implement a pipeline" - it's very tricky. Don't forget to always google for "whatever twisted" when you want to find how to do whatever. Scrapy is a Twisted application and unless you used Twisted-related techniques (not e.g. `urllib`) your performance will suffer. There are a few examples here: https://github.com/scalingexcellence/scrapybook/tree/master/ch09/properties/properties/pipelines