# Scrapy ImagesPipeline not downloading images

Tags: python, image, scrapy

I'm running a Scrapy spider in python to scrape images from a website. After trying some other methods, I'm attempting to implement an ImagesPipeline for doing this.

**items.py**

```
class NHTSAItem(scrapy.Item):
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
    images = scrapy.Field()
```

**settings.py:**

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1}
IMAGES_STORE = 'C:\Users\me\Desktop'
```

**myspider.py**

```
def parse_photo_page(self, response):
    item = NHTSAItem()
    for sel in response.xpath('//table[@id="tblData"]/tr'):
        url = sel.xpath('td/font/a/@href').extract()
        table_fields = sel.xpath('td/font/text()').extract()
        if url:
            base_url_photo = "http://www-nrd.nhtsa.dot.gov"
            full_url = base_url_photo + url[0]
            if not item:
                item['image_urls'] = [full_url]
            else: 
                item['image_urls'].append(full_url)
    return item
```

There are no errors that come up, the images just don't get downloaded. The debugger even says "Scraped" Here's the log:

```
DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www-nrd.nhtsa.dot.gov/database/VSR/veh/../SearchMedia.aspx?database=v&tstno=4000&mediatype=p&p_tstno=4000>
{'image_urls': [u'http://www-nrd.nhtsa.dot.gov/database/MEDIA/GetMedia.aspx?tstno=4000&index=1&database=V&type=P',
            u'http://www-nrd.nhtsa.dot.gov/database/MEDIA/GetMedia.aspx?tstno=4000&index=2&database=V&type=P',
            u'http://www-nrd.nhtsa.dot.gov/database/MEDIA/GetMedia.aspx?tstno=4000&index=3&database=V&type=P',
            u'http://www-nrd.nhtsa.dot.gov/database/MEDIA/GetMedia.aspx?tstno=4000&index=4&database=V&type=P',
            u'http://www-nrd.nhtsa.dot.gov/database/MEDIA/GetMedia.aspx?tstno=4000&index=5&database=V&type=P']}
```

I don't care about extending the pipeline (making a custom pipeline), the default imagespipeline is fine. The images are nowhere to be found. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure what the issue is. Could it be about the `IMAGES_STORE` on Windows? Here's a working example on Ubuntu: https://gist.github.com/redapple/396faaaaf8fcc0f77c10

Comment: What have you got in 'allowed_domains`?

Comment: Those are asp.net references and I don't think scrapy will touch them. Try using selenium ad scrapy together.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, guys. 
`allowed_domains = ["nhtsa.gov", "nhtsa.dot.gov", "www-nrd.nhtsa.dot.gov"]`
How can I tell if they are asp.net references? I can successful download data (.tsv) and video files (.avi) from this source, so wouldn't images be okay too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution, which came to me from this parallel question: [Scrapy: Error 10054 after retrying image download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35852744/scrapy-error-10054-after-retrying-image-download) (Thanks to @neverlastn)

I simply added this snippet to my actual spider.py file.

```
custom_settings = {
    "ITEM_PIPELINES": {'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1},
    "IMAGES_STORE": saveLocation
}
```

I think it wasn't properly referencing my settings.py file, and therefore didn't activate the image pipeline. I'm not sure how to get it to accurately reference my settings file, but this solution is good enough for me!

Comment: why is this even happenig?

Answer (score 1):

If you applied all the process as described in https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html

The last thing you have to apply is to install `Pillow` library.

This is a 5 steps process to properly download images in Scrapy:

1- Define `image_urls` and `images` fields inside `items.py`

```
 image_urls = scrapy.Field()
 images = scrapy.Field()
```

2- Active Scrapy images pipeline inside `settings.py` file:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1}
```

3- Set images download folder path inside `settings.py` file:

```
IMAGES_STORE = 'path_to_your_folder'
```

4- install Pillow library:

```
pip install pillow
```

5- Inside your spider file, assign image URLs to the item `image_urls` field:

```
item = SpiderItem()
item['image_urls'] = ['set_images_urls_here']
# do other stuff if needed....

yield item
```

When you follow these 5 steps, you will successfully download images with `Scrapy`

Answer (score -1):

try replacing in your `settings.py`

```
IMAGES_STORE = 'C:\Users\me\Desktop'
```

with:

```
IMAGES_STORE = import os
IMAGES_STORE = os.getcwd()
```

If it works, it's a problem with the format of the absolute path. Then either of those should work:

```
IMAGES_STORE = 'C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop'
```

or

```
IMAGES_STORE = 'C:/Users/me/Desktop'
```

P.S. This is the  `settings.py`. The relative XPaths issue from the other question/answer also applies here.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. I'm going to accept the other solution that I pulled from your other answer.